# Line 103:9: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

1. I keep getting this error but I don't know why code below

```js
class AccountInfo extends Component {
  render() {
    const awards = <Tooltip id="view">View profile awards</Tooltip>;
    const channel = <Tooltip id="edit">Update channel page</Tooltip>;
    const verified = <Tooltip id="remove">Verified</Tooltip>;
    <td className="td-actions text-right">
      <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={awards}>
        <Button simple bsStyle="info" bsSize="xs">
          <i className="fa fa-user" />
        </Button>
      </OverlayTrigger>
      <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={channel}>
        <Button simple bsStyle="success" bsSize="xs">
          <i className="fa fa-edit" />
        </Button>
      </OverlayTrigger>
      <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={verified}>
        <Button simple bsStyle="danger" bsSize="xs">
          <i className="fa fa-times" />
        </Button>
      </OverlayTrigger>
    </td>;
  }
}
```

> Line 103:9: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Comment: Your question is not appropriate , Do trying pasting you code in code brackets , that will help people to understand the question first

Comment: Please provide the error. Assuming it is something like "Your render method should have return statement"

Comment: Can you tell us what like 103 is?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are not returning anything from your render function.

Try updating with.

```js
class AccountInfo extends Component {
  render() {
    const awards = <Tooltip id="view">View profile awards</Tooltip>;
    const channel = <Tooltip id="edit">Update channel page</Tooltip>;
    const verified = <Tooltip id="remove">Verified</Tooltip>;
    return (
      <td className="td-actions text-right">
        <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={awards}>
          <Button simple bsStyle="info" bsSize="xs">
            <i className="fa fa-user" />
          </Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
        <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={channel}>
          <Button simple bsStyle="success" bsSize="xs">
            <i className="fa fa-edit" />
          </Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
        <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={verified}>
          <Button simple bsStyle="danger" bsSize="xs">
            <i className="fa fa-times" />
          </Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
      </td>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this change didn't resolve the error.